# Apex Charts updating options from having data to none

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

Hello I'm using two different Apex Options. Below I will put the name just for reference.

```js
  const chartOptionsBalance = useCallback(
    (id: string): ApexOptions => ({
      chart: {
        background: "transparent",
        id,
        },
      }....

const chartOptionsNoBalanceData = useCallback(
    (id: string): ApexOptions => ({
      chart: {
        id
    ....
}
```

What Im trying to do based on my pedal_left_balance is to show the one that has and the other one that doesnt.

My problem is if I go from a tab that I have to none its okay. But when i go from a none to having I still have the old options.

I will post below what I'm trying but it doesnt work

```js
  const balanceOptions = useMemo(
    () =>
      filteredStatistics[0].pedal_balance_left !== null
        ? chartOptionsBalance("Balance")
        : chartOptionsNoBalanceData("Balance"),
    [],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return filteredStatistics[0].pedal_balance_left !== null
      ? ApexCharts.exec(
          "Balance",
          "updateOptions",
          chartOptionsBalance("Balance"),
          true,
        )
      : ApexCharts.exec(
          "Balance",
          "updateOptions",
          chartOptionsNoBalanceData("Balance"),
          true,
        );
  }, [props.currentTabStat]);
```